# How can I initialize Zend_Form_Element_Select with a config array?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I tried:

```
$form->addElement(
    'select',
    'salutation',
    array(
        'required' => true,
        'options' => array(
            'Mr.' => 'Mr.',
            'Mrs.' => 'Mrs.',
            'Ms.' => 'Ms.',
        ), 
    )
);
```

Then I `print_r()`ed the form, and options for salutation are empty. Does anybody know the correct spell for that? As far as I see, there's no documentation for Zend element configs' format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use 'multiOptions' instead of 'options'.